# How can I open several tabs in a one new browser window?

Tags: javascript, tabs, window

I'm trying to create a web page that opens two separate browser tabs in the same window. However, using `window.open` appears to open two separate windows, instead of two browser tabs within the same new window.

I attempted to open http://en.wikipedia.org and http://jsfiddle.net in the same browser window, but each tab was opened in a separate window instead:

```
window.open("http://www.jsfiddle.net/", "newWindow", "height=200,width=200");
window.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/", "newWindow", "height=200,width=200");
```

[What am I doing wrong here](http://jsfiddle.net/hzGAd/), and what is the correct way to open multiple tabs in a single new window using JavaScript?

Comment: AFAIK, pure JavaScript does not have the power to do that. It would require utilizing vendor-specific methods that may or may not be available... also it may depend on the user's preferences.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on browsers setting that usually is part of user preferences and there is no specific trick to force a browser to behave in certain way!

Comment: How do the user preferences make it possible to open multiple links in a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this lines, it should work.

```
    <a class="link1">Link 1</a>
    <a class="link2">Link 2</a>
      <script  type="text/javascript">
            $("a.link1").on("click",function(){
               window.open('http://www.jsfiddle.net/','_blank');
            });
            $("a.link2").on("click",function(){
               window.open('http://en.wikipedia.org/','_blank');
            });
      </script>
```

I think the ablove lines of code may not work in all the browsers, we can do it in other way by setting the target value for the anchor tag as follows.

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: In which browsers have you tested this script?

Answer (score 0):

Opening a webpage URL in window or tab depends on user's preferences in browser settings. Modern browsers do not allow a web application or webpage to change this behavior. But you can create a browser add-on or extension to override user's browser settings and can open a page in a tab or window using the extension.